# Lombok's @SuperBuilder - Error java: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, lombok

I've been using Lombok with IntelliJ for a while now. I have installed newest (v. 0.28) Lombok plugin, enabled annotation processing and added a Lombok dependency (v. 1.18.10) in pom.xml. It all worked well until today, when I wanted to implement the experimental **@SuperBuilder**.

I have a simple hierarchy:

```
@SuperBuilder
public class User {
   private String a;
}

@SuperBuilder
public class Employee extends User {
   private int b;
}

@SuperBuilder
public class Employer extends User {
   private double c;
}
```

I wanted to set the fields from parent's class in child's builder, e.g.:

```
Employee.builder().a("Positive").b(1).build();

Employer.builder().a("Negative").c(-2.1).build();
```

At the first glance it all seems to work - there are no errors displayed when the file is open and the builder is fine. However after *mvn clean compile* I get the following result on every @SuperBuilder line (i.e. in each of those 3 classes):
`Error:(20) java: cannot find symbol`

What am I missing here? I tried updating Lombok plugin version and reinstalling it, but without any success.

Comment: Not sure how much more anyone here will be able to answer given the amount of information. If the error is "*cannot find symbol*" then the compiler can't even see the annotation. This is a dependency issue rather than anything to do with Lombok.

Comment: But how would you explain the ability to access the decompiled SuperBuilder.class file? It all seem to be there

Comment: That means IntelliJ is able to locate the dependency, but it doesn't work via the same mechanism as Maven.

Comment: There is probably something wrong in your pom. Could you add the relevant part (the dependency to Lombok)?

Comment: I cannot format it properly here, but it looks exactly like here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.10

Comment: That looks correct. Is there anything more to that compiler error? Only because it is in the line of `@SuperBuilder` does not mean that it can't find the annotation. It may as well be another symbol in the generated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I missed that the User class was extending a basic class every entity in our application extends. It seemed so obvious and yet I didn't notice...

Anyway, I found out only by running the *mvn clean install* in terminal - the output was much more verbose than the one in IntelliJ and it pointed out this class. After adding **@SuperBuilder** annotation on top of it compilation was successful.

But **@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)** is the right way of using it.

Answer (score 20):

I've faced same issue and **adding** `@SuperBuilder` **to the all "base" classes** solved the issue.

Before:

```
abstract class Parent {
   ...
}

@SuperBuilder
class Child extends Parent {
   ...
}
```

After:

```
@SuperBuilder              // <- addded
abstract class Parent {
   ...
}

@SuperBuilder
class Child extends Parent {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. can you also explain why?